# Plotting a chart in excel - advice on visualizing data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Bit rusty with Excel charts. Have been playing around/googling for a few hours now and can't seem to get a chart how i want it.

Basically I have something like the following data set:

[image]

I am trying to show a visual representation of the above of when a certain days file gets delivered and the trend over time. I thought about a scatter chart, and this works fine, if i ignore the date dimension of the second column (which isn't much use).

I am after something like this:
[image]

Does it even make sense how i am trying to depict it or am i being stupid? Any thoughts of a better method of visualization on a chart? Maybe a chart isn't the right way to visualise this information.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide more context about the data, e.g. how many times a day are you expecting this file to be delivered? What is it you are trying to show with the chart in terms of narrative?

Comment: files should be delivered on a t+1 basis, i.e. yesterdays file, comes today. I want to essentially show where the files are being delivered late (i.e. a  T-1 file should be provided on t+1 by 11AM BST)..so how do i show when the files come t+2 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having date on one axis and time on another is not really intuitive in my experience. I think we're looking for a relationship between the date created and the date delivered. So, one way you could do it is as follows:

First, create new columns that format your columns as dates instead of text.

Date of File Formatted:

```
=DATE(MID(A2,7,4),MID(A2,4,2),LEFT(A2,2))
```

Date & Time Delivered Formatted:

```
=DATE(MID(B2,7,4),MID(B2,4,2),LEFT(B2,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(B2,5))
```

[image]

The results of these formulas will show the month and day in the order specified by your computer's regional settings.

Now select the two new columns and create a scatterchart. It will start as something like this:

[image]

Click the orange dots and press delete on the keyboard.

Now right click the blue dots and choose "Select data". Edit Series 1 and select the X and Y values in the Edit Series dialog:

[image]

After you exit both dialogs, the dots will be in the right place. You can now format the chart the way you want it to appear.

I have removed the time from the Data of File Formatted column so I don't have the time showing on the X-axis. I've also removed the legend and added data labels as callouts. I wouldn't normally do this kind of thing as you have to manually position the callouts so when new data are added, it becomes a bit tedious to maintain. That said, if you're only preparing this chart once, it might be OK.

[image]

Now that I look at this, I wonder whether it's actually the *distance* between the two dates that's interesting.

So, you could subtract column D from column C in the screenshot above, and plot that as bars:

[image]

Comment: this is amazing, thank you so much